# Django Model Importerror: cannot import name 'Driver' from 'driver.models'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two apps : vehicle and driver . Each vehicle can have 2 unique drivers at any given time.

my issue : I not sure if this should be manytomany relationship or manytoone relationship.

while trying manytomany relationship (as per the below models), i get an error during makemigrations stating cannot import name 'Driver' from 'driver.models'

**driver.models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from vehicle.models import Vehicle

class DriverStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.status}'

class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    driver_num = models.IntegerField()
    profile_image = models.ImageField(default="default.jpg",upload_to="images")
    status = models.ForeignKey(DriverStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    current_vehicle = models.ManyToManyField(Vehicle)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

**vehicle.models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from driver.models import Driver


class VehicleStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.status}'



class Vehicle(models.Model):
    vehicle_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    driver_main = models.ManyToManyField(Driver)
    driver_sec = models.ManyToManyField(Driver)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to circular import you are getting the error. So either you have to change the configuration or remove the import and put Driver in quotes

```
driver_main = models.ManyToManyField("Driver" )
```